# Using fscanf until EOF without using getc

Tags: c, eof, scanf

I have a text file of composed of sequences of 2 bytes which I have to store in an array.

I have declared `FILE *ptr`.

How can I loop until EOF without using the method:

```
while(c = getc() != EOF)
{
// do something 
}
```

I want to implement something along the lines of (PSEUDOCODE):

```
while (ptr is not pointing to the end of the file)
{
fscanf(...)  // I will read in the bytes etc.
}
```

The getc() method wouldn't work well for me because I am reading in blocks of 2 bytes at a time.

Comment: You're missing parentheses and an argument on the first example; you need `while ((c = getc(ptr)) != EOF)`. Also `ptr` is not a good name for a `FILE*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fread` to read more than one byte at a time. `fread` returns the number of items it was able to read.

For example, to read 2-byte chunks you might use:

```
while ((fread(target, 2, 1, ptr) == 1) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Here `2` is the number of bytes in each "item", and `1` is the number of "items" you want to read on each call.

In general, you shouldn't use `feof()` to control when to terminate an input loop. Use the value returned by whichever input routine you're using. Different input functions vary in the information they provide; you'll have to read the documentation for the one you're using.

Note that this will treat an end-of-line as a single `'\n'` character. You say you're reading from a text file; it's not clear how you want to handle line endings. You should also decide what you want to do if the file has an odd number of characters.

Another option is to call `getc()` twice in the loop, checking its result both times.

Comment: The problem with using fread is that my file pointer will be moved each time the condition is checked in the while loop. I have to call an fscanf function inside of the while loop, so I cannot have the file pointer changed in the while condition.

Comment: @user3501476: If you're using `fscanf` to read input, then you need to use the result returned by `fscanf` to determine when the loop is finished. It's not clear from your question just what you're doing. What exactly do you mean when you say the input file is composed of sequences of 2 bytes? Does that include whitespace? Newlines?

Comment: The "Note that this will treat an end-of-line as a single '\n' ..." needs to be be qualified with the words "not necessarily".   fread() does binary input and some systems represent newline as a pair of characters (particularly if input is taken from a file on disk, including redirection of stdin to come from a file).

Comment: @Peter: That's incorrect. `fread` reads in the mode for the stream it's reading from. By definition, it works as if by repeatedly calling `fgetc`. For example, if you're on a Windows system using `fread` to read a text file that was opened in text mode, the CR-LF pair marking the end of a line will be read as a single `\n'` character. If the file was opened in binary mode, it will read two characters. (`fread` is most commonly used to read binary files opened in binary mode.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to tell when you've reached the end of the file is when you try to read past it, and the read fails.  (Yes, there is an [`feof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/feof.html) function, but it only returns true *after* you've tried to read past the end of the file.)

This means that, if you're going to use `fscanf()` to read your input, it's the return value of `fscanf()` itself that you need to check.

Specifically, [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) returns the number of items it has successfully read, or `EOF` (which is a negative value, typically -1) if the input ended before anything at all could be read.  Thus, your input loop might look something like this:

```c
while (1) {
    /* ... */

    int n = fscanf(ptr, "...", ...);

    if (n == EOF && !ferror(ptr)) {
        /* we've reached the end of the input; stop the loop */
        break;
    } else if (n < items_requested) {
        if (ferror(ptr)) perror("Error reading input file");
        else fprintf(stderr, "Parse error or unexpected end of input!\n");
        exit(1);  /* or do whatever you want to handle the error */
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

That said, there may be other options, too.  For example, if your input is structured as lines (which a lot of text input is), [you may be better off](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) reading the input line by line with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html), and then parsing the lines e.g. with `sscanf()`.

Also, technically, there *is* a way to peek one byte ahead in the input, using [`ungetc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ungetc.html).  That is, you *could* do something like this:

```
int c;
while ((c = getc(ptr)) != EOF) {
    ungetc(c, ptr);
    /* ... now read and parse the input ... */
}
```

The problem is that this only checks that you can read *one* more byte before EOF; it doesn't, and *can't*, actually check that your `fscanf()` call will have enough data to match all the requested items.  Thus, you still need to check the return value of `fscanf()` anyway — and if you're going to do that, you might as well use it for EOF detection too.